# Dynamic Content Animate Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the blackbox will animate to auto height width when   clicked on button.
Unfortunately i saw a SO post(link i forgot) its not working for me. 
Where im wrong js junkies ?

https://jsfiddle.net/3m7ue8dj/

```js
$('#vote').click(function(){
   var w = $('.whitebox');
   var b = $('.blackbox');
    if(!b.hasClass('taco')){
       b.html(w.html());
     }else{
       b.html('I will build a wall.')
     }
    b.toggleClass('taco');
  mainListAnimate(b);
});
  function mainListAnimate(mainlist){
   var timing = 1000;
   mainlist.animate({height: mainlist.get(0).scrollHeight,width: mainlist.get(0).scrollWidth}, timing , function() { mainlist.height('auto');mainlist.width('auto');}); 
  }
```

```css
.whitebox{
  display:none;
}
.blackbox{
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  max-height:250px;
  padding:10px;
  max-width:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  transition:.15s linear all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="vote">Vote for Trump</button>
<br />
<div class="blackbox">
I will build a Wall.
</div>

<div class="whitebox">I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.I will build a Wall.
</div>
```

### Heading

Comment: seems to do its job. define 'not working'

Comment: when you hover over any tags on `SO` it animates in a way similarly i want that effect but in a toggle way

Comment: **"Defination"**  - *The changing from one state or condition to another of the measurement or extent of it from side to side and the measurement of it from head to foot or from base to top  is not without indentations where it = ".blackbox"*  @Brian